# Authentication providers on a custom community login page

Tags: community, auth-provider

We have defined custom Auth. Providers (like for facebook or google or itsme) and would like to expose them to my visualforce community. 
On this community we have implemented a custom login page (visualforce page + component) where we would like to be able to expose those custom Auth. Providers.

Is there an apex method available to get and display those alternative login methods? Does anyone know how it works on the standard community login page?

Thanks

Comment: Example from [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Auth_AuthConfiguration.htm?search_text=authprovider) . If I was doing it, I'd simply inline them into my custom page.